# Woocommerce and Woocommerce Product Vendors plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have 2 slightly related questions 1 general php and 1 not so general:

1st. I'm trying to pass a integer value in a WP do_shortcode statement but the value doesn't seem to work, the code looks like this:

```
$current_user = (wp_get_current_user()); 
$test1 = ($current_user->id) ;
$bulk_shop_display = do_shortcode( '[bulkshop categories="'. $test1 . '" hidedescription="true"]' );
echo $bulk_shop_display ;
```

The do_shortcode works fine when a number is added to categories but not when a variable is used.

```
$bulk_shop_display = do_shortcode( '[bulkshop categories="60" hidedescription="true"]' );
```

2nd question.
Woocommerce Product Vendors plugin assigns a vendor id number which is visible in the admin table (last column) how can I get this id number to use in a variable?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_wcmp_vendor_id_by_store_url($store_url) {
   $vendor_id = false;
   $termslug = basename($store_url);
   $term = get_term_by('slug', $termslug, 'dc_vendor_shop');
   if ($term) {
       $vendor = get_wcmp_vendor_by_term($term->term_id);
       $vendor_id = $vendor ? $vendor->id : false;
   }
   return $vendor_id;
}
```

Try using this for getting vendor id : change store url to your site url